# OnClick vertical menu instead of hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a problem with my vertical menu instead of hover I need to open submenus using onclick and after onclick the menu has to be opened and it should get transition with maximum height. I am trying to solve this problem but I couldn't solved can anyone help me in solving this? Do I need to use javascript or can I solve it using CSS, I don't understand please help me.

```css
*{padding:0px;margin:1px;margin-top:-0.01em;margin-left:-0.05em;margin-right:0.1em;border-radius:8px;}
    body{font:16px/1 Times;background-color:#FAFCFD;}
    nav.vertical{position:absolute;background:#5798B4;}
    nav.vertical ul{list-style: none;}
    nav.vertical ul ul{position:relative;}
    nav.vertical li{position:relative;}
    nav.vertical a{display:inherit;color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;padding:8px 12px;transition:2.5s;}
    nav.vertical li:hover > a{background:#FAFCFD;font-weight:bold;color:#000;}
    nav.vertical ul ul{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.01);padding-left:20px;transition: max-height 2.2s ease-out;max-height:0;overflow:hidden;}
    nav.vertical li:hover > ul{max-height:500px;transition: max-height 2.5s ease-in;}
```

```html
    <nav class="vertical">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Configuration +</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">IP Configuration +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Address Config +</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">LAN IP</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">WAN IP</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">L2TP IP</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">NAT +</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">NAT</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">IPv4v6 Static Mapping</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Port Forwarding</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">WiZ/RTU Port Mapping</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Management Config</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">IPSec VPN +</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">IPSec Configuration</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Tunnel Configuration</a></li> 
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">L2TP VPN</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Dial Up +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Dial Up Params</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Dial Up Scripts +</a>
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Modem Init Commands</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Dial Out Commands</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Hang Up Commands</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">SMS Commands</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">PPP</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">SMS +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Source Mobile Number</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">SMS Alarm Parameter</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Date & Time</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Log +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Log Params</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Log Event</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Log Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">External Network +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Ext. N/W Connection</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Target IP</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">SNMP +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">System</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Trap</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">DTU +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">DTU Application</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">RS232</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">System Control +</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Save</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Reboot</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Factory Defaults</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">System Maintenance</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Diagnostics +</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Ping</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Trace Route</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Status +</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">System</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">WAN</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">LAN</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">PPP</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Log Status +</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Show All Logs</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Show Logs From</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Cell Info.</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">VPN Status</a></li>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Traps +</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Generic</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Quick Config</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question :S

Comment: Please give a short example of your code with the important and not working parts only.

Comment: It would be much easier if you wrap your code in a code snippet...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line from :

```
nav.vertical li:hover > ul{max-height:500px;transition: max-height 2.5s ease-in;}
```

to

```
nav.vertical li:active > ul, nav.vertical li:focus > ul{max-height:500px;transition: max-height 2.5s ease-in;}
```

Comment: It works only if you keep the holding click over the `li`, if you release, the menu closes

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible with pure CSS. You can consider using JS.

I would recommend you using a class like `.clicked` and instead of `:hover` using that class. Then you can add an `onclick` event to the `li` elements with some code that changes the tag like:

```
<li onclick="this.className='clicked'">...</li>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, got a little thing wrong. Just edited it. Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

The effect you want cannot be achieved using the css mouse pseudo classes, this mechanism involves a toggle switch on mouse drown, the input type checkbox can provide what you need.

```
<INPUT type="checkbox">
```

The checkbox is only used to provide the UIs functionality you require - toggling the part of the UI the user wants to navigate to.

Radio buttons can be utilised for a similar UX.

The effect, with a click toggle, can be achieved without JavaScript often creating a complex state machine

You can use a label element to link the mouse effect with any input element:

```
<LABEL TYPE='checkbox' ID='clientCheckbox1' />
<LABEL FOR='clientCheckbox1'>IP Configuration</LABEL>
<UL>
Submenu content here.
</UL>
```

Each `<A>` tag setup for menu navigation in the original post can be setup in this way - to achieve the effect without JavaScript.

The CSS below will achieve the effect as required by initialising the trasition once the checkbox is clicked.

The ~ / + sibling selectors pick up all / adjacent silbling respectively.

```
INPUT:checked~UL{
   max-height:500px;
   Transition: max-height:2.5s ease-in
}
INPUT~UL {
   max-height:0;
   transition: max-height 2.2s ease-out
}
```

Comment: I need menus to be  displayed onclick their corresponding url

Comment: The checkbox input's onclick can be triggered using a <label for=<checkbox id>> you can also display:none and the dropdowns will behave as required - onclick of the content surrounded by the <label> tag

Comment: Sorry to say but it doesn't worked what is the problem I don't understand...can you please suggest any other solution,

Comment: Hi Sowmya, please find further details in my latest edit

Comment: Thank you Phil...Let me try this:-)

Comment: Thank you Phil :-) for helping me. You have solved my problem without using any JavaScript. Thanks a lot once again....

Comment: This works fine in firefox , google chrome and Edge but it is not working in ie7 and ie8. Onclick Transition effect is not working in internet explorer please find edited code.

Comment: My solution is not responsive for IE < 9, IE before version 9 did not have a checked pseudo class, nor did it use event listeners, the solution for older browsers would probably best be pulled together using a JavaScript function as suggested by D. Pardal - the onclick event changes the class name, don't forget to add a css rule for the new class and some way to hide the submenu afterwards